# Obliquity factor in Huygens principle

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction, huygens-principle

What is the derivation of the [obliquity factor](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=obliquity+factor) (intensity proportional to 1+cosø,where ø is the angle between direction of wave propagation and wavefront tangent at some point on the envelop) used in the field of wave optics under Huygens principle?

Comment: Look at Kirchhoff's diffraction formula which contains parameters arbitrarily assigned in the Huygens equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_diffraction_formula

Comment: The mathematical derivation can be found in Godman "Intro to Fourier Optics". However, as stated [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543598/intuition-of-inclination-factor-in-kirchhoffs-diffraction-law) it turns out that this factor has no simple "quasi-physical" explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a derivation from the most elementary principles, including an abstract and a conclusion: "**[Consistent derivation of Kirchhoff's integral theorem and diffraction formula and the Maggi-Rubinowicz transformation using high-school math](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.7205781)**".

A theory of diffraction can be constructed on three principles: causality, superposition, and the assumption that the wave function had a beginning. Given a region *R* containing no sources and separated from the remaining region *R'* by a surface *S*, these principles suffice to show that if the ("primary") sources in *R'* are *replaced* by a distribution of ("secondary") sources on *S*, such that the step-changes in the wave function and its normal derivative, in crossing from *R'* to *R*, are respectively equal to the original wave function and its normal derivative on *S*, then we get the original wave function in *R* and a null wave function in *R'* (no backward secondary waves). By further assuming the form of the wave function due to a monopole source, we obtain the distribution of monopole and dipole sources over *S* that causes the desired step-changes ("saltus conditions"). Adding the contributions from these secondary sources yields an integral expressing the wave function in *R* in terms of the boundary conditions at the *R* side of *S*. The Kirchhoff integral theorem follows by elementary rules of differentiation. In the case of a *single monopole primary source*, the spatial derivatives in the Kirchhoff integrand can be expressed in terms of angles, yielding the Kirchhoff
diffraction formula and its far-field obliquity factor, which reduces to the familiar ${(1+\cos\chi)\big/2}$  if *S* is a spherical primary wavefront.

Comment: It would be highly desirable if you can provide the derivation, or at least an outline of it, instead of just a link.

Comment: @flippiefanus this has happened :-)